# Java: Slice Array To End

Tags: java

I have a string array with at least three elements. I'd like to copy the third and all subsequent elements into a new array. How can this be most efficiently achieved?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
String[] arr = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};

String[] arr2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 2, arr.length); 
//Note third param is exclusive
```

Comment: If I'm reading the docs correctly, this also works when `arr` only has 2 elements, i.e. when `arr2` would end up empty.