# Translate javascript code below into java

Tags: javascript, java, translate

I have javascript code like this:

```
var myArray = []; //integer
var anIndex = 1;
Array.prototype.delete = function (index) {
    var rest = this.slice(index + 1);
    this.length = index;
    return this.push.apply(this, rest);
};
```

and used like this:

```
myArray.delete(anIndex);
```

How to translate it into java code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15300432/3166303

Comment: What's wrong with `delete anArray[idx]`, or why not slice the array in de first place? Why augment the prototype (which is considered bad practice)? besides: questions asking to rewrite a snippet in another language are considered off-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What java collection are you using?

If you are using `java.util.List`, it has a method `.remove(int index)` that does what you require -- removes an element from array.

If you are using java arrays (e.g. `int[]`), consider using collections such as `java.util.ArrayList` instead, they have the methods you need.